# What is the prefered format to set the values of a many-to-many relationship field using TYPO3 DataHandler?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

It seems to be possible to either use an array or a comma separated list to set the values of a many-to-many relationship field in [TYPO3 DataHandler's](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Database/Index.html) `$data` array:

Set category values for a news record as an array:

```
$data['tx_news_domain_model_news']['NEW98765432'] = [
    'categories' => [1,2,3],
);
```

Set category values for a news record as a comma separated list:

```
$data['tx_news_domain_model_news']['NEW98765432'] = [
    'categories' => '1,2,3',
];
```

Are there any differences between the two formats? Which one is the prefered format?

Answer (score 0):

The preferable way would be using an MM-table for that purpose, so that the field itself contains the number of relations as an integer value in the end.

If you still want to go for a CSV list, IMHO the string should be the way to go, since it will be stored as a string in the end too, so there should be less overhead to convert it.

Comment: Oh, you got me wrong. There is a MM-table. Think of _tt_content_ or _news_ records that are categorized by system categories. MM-table is _sys_category_record_mm_. In this setup it is possible to set category relationships as an array or as a comma separated list. Doesn't seem to make any difference. The relationships will be saved correctly to the MM-table. DataHandler's documentation uses an array in one of the examples. Extension _news_ uses a comma separated list. In my use case both formats were used in a backend hook. So i was wondering what the difference is. If there is any.